# style ul with width to accommodate items

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, html-lists, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Sorry I could not find a similar answer on SO. I have the following markup (generated by jquery ui autocomplete but this is not the issue here)

```
<ul style="z-index: 1; display: block; border: thin solid red; width: 200px;">
<li>
<a>
  <div style="font-size: 0.85em;">
    <span style="float: right; padding-left: 10px; color: gray;">
      United Kingdom
    </span>
    <span style="">text text text text text</span>
  </div>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fVr8P/2/ the text wraps because the width is limited and the country span is "floating". What I would like would be for the width to enlarge to accommodate the full length, but if I put `width: auto;` it will expand to 100%.

**Background**

The ul is of course coming from jquery ui autocomplete. I am styling the results a bit using the autocomplete.html extension. Problem is that everything is working ok in firefox an chrome because the autocomplete is set to the correct width on creation. in IE this does not happen (width is too small) so the text wraps. I am hping to come to a simple css only solution, without fiddling around in jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try this one:

```
<ul style="z-index: 1; border: thin solid red; list-style: none outside none; float: left;">
```

And replace your span style with this:

```
<span style="float: left;">text text text text text</span>
```

Comment: That seemed to do the job. I had to assign an "height" to the `a` tag or the highlight on hover would just be a narrow line above the actual line. It is a bit hacky but it actually looks like the best solution. Will do some further cross-browsing tests... :)

Comment: Accepting as it pointed in the right direction. Since I had no control over the ul styling (jquery UI adding its own stuff there) I had to alter the "a" style just so that it has a height.

Answer (score 0):

Add `width:auto; display:inline-block`

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/fVr8P/4/

Comment: Yep, that works... problem is that the display property is being changed by jQuery UI (which uses only "block" and "none"). Any other ideas?

Comment: You can use inline-block in your jquery instead of block. Check the sample demo here http://jsfiddle.net/YyU73/1/

Comment: I did that and it works ok with Chrome and Firefox, but dunno why IE is not moving... even if I manually change the css in the dev console the menu just does not resize and the text stays wrapped...

Answer (score 0):

Replace `display: block` with `display: inline-block` and `width: 200px` with `width: auto`, that should do the trick.